# Phusion Messenger virtual host

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to run a ruby application server with phusion passenger. The problem is that the application is hosted on an apache server that hosts other websites too. So I tried to implement virtualhost. Now for some reason I can't reach my application. The DNS does redirect the queries, but its to another website being hosted on the server. The phusion passenger is running on port 3000, and the virtualhost file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
ServerAdmin admin@something.com
ServerName something.com
ServerAlias www.something.com

# !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public/    
RailsEnv development 
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

<Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
# This relaxes Apache security settings.

AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny  
#MultiViews must be turned off.
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +ExecCGI 
# Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there were two problems:

1. `<VirtualHost *:3000>` should have been `<VirtualHost *:80>`
2. `<Directory /var/www/redmine/public>` should have been `<Directory /var/www/redmine/public/>`. Just one small slash, after public, it made the difference.